# KDB+/Q: How to create a column that increments the occurrence of unique values of another column?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to create a column that increments the occurrence of unique (not the same as the previous) values in another column as such:

```
x   y
=====
1 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 1
4 | 2
1 | 3
```

How could one achieve this functionality in kdb+?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
q)t:([]x:1 1 2 4 1)
q)update y:(sums 0b,1_differ x)from t
x y
---
1 0
1 0
2 1
4 2
1 3
```

`differ` looks at a list (or column of a table) and returns a list that is `1b` in positions where the item is different to the item before that. It always starts with `1b` though, so we have to drop the first element of the list using `1_` and add a `0b` at the beginning with `0b,`. Then we just take the running sum using `sums`.

Comment: Nice!, Thank you

Comment: You can avoid dropping the first element by passing a first/seed value into differ: `update y:sums differ[first x;x] from t`. Alternatively differ and subtract one: `update y:-1+sums differ x from t`